# How to trigger an ASP.NET MVC 4 method in the Controller via ajax request

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller

this is my first question on SO, so it's probably something basic.
I created a button in order to trigger a method in the Controller via an ajax request.
I am getting this error:
The message cannot be deserialized into MessageContract type FXM.Ordering.WS.Contract.BoCreateAffiliateRequest since it does not have a default (parameterless) constructor.

I tried to modify the ajax request and rechecked all parts of my code but it didn't solve the problem.

My button:

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <div>
                <input type="button" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" id="create-affiliate-button" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

The ajax request:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        refreshGroups();
        $('#create-affiliate-button').click(function (e) {
            console.log("blahblahblah");

            var b = $("form").serialize();
            console.log("formvalues", b);

            $.ajax({
                url: "/en/AjaxUI/CreateAffiliate",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                data: b,
       
                //error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                //    failMessage();
                //}
            });
        });
    });

    function refreshGroups() {
        var pltf = "MT4_LIVE";
        var out = $('#MT4Group');
        if (pltf != null && pltf !== "") {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/' + window.currentLangCulture + '/BOLiveForms/GetPlatformGroupByFilter',
                data: {
                    platform: pltf, currency: "", withId : true
                },
                type: 'GET',
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('#tpLoader').show();
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $('#tpLoader').hide();
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    populateDropDown(out, data);
                }
            });
        } else {
            out.empty();
            out.append($('<option></option>').val('').html(window.defaultSelection));
        }
    }
```

The method I am trying to call in the Controller

```
        public JsonResult CreateAffiliate(NewAffiliateViewModel newAffiliateViewModel)
        {
            try
            {
                var res = BackOfficeServices.BoAddAffiliateUser(newAffiliateViewModel);
                return Json("success");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

What am I missing?
Where/How to add this default (parameterless) constructor?

---

UPDATE after adding the parameterless constructor as suggested.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace FXM.BO.ViewModels
{
    public class NewAffiliateViewModel
    {
        public NewAffiliateViewModel()
        {
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string AffiliateName { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }


        public int Employee { get; set; }


        public int MT4Group { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might need to go the route of using dependency injection, or as answered, a default constructor to initialize whatever is required as constructor args. Hard to know without more context.

Answer (score 1):

**Add a parameterless construct**or to your `NewAffiliateViewModel` class:

```
public class NewAffiliateViewModel
{
    public NewAffiliateViewModel()
    {
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Strangely so, after adding the parameterless constructor I am still getting the same error.

Comment: What about your controller? Does that have a constructor with params?

Answer (score 0):

Try use `@Url.Action()` for this purpose.

```
       $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("CreateAffiliate", "AjaxUI")",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                     newAffiliateViewModel : b
            },
   
            //error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            //    failMessage();
            //}
        });
```

**#EDIT 1:**

So you can pass complex objects, like your class. You need to parse JSON inside controller action, and in Action parameter set this:

```
     public JsonResult CreateAffiliate(string newAffiliateJSON)
            {
                try
                {
                    //here you need to deserizlize variable newAffiliateJSON 
                    //to object try this helper: https://json2csharp.com/
                    //something like that Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); (and you need to create new class, that describes your json (get it on site i write upper))
                    var res = BackOfficeServices.BoAddAffiliateUser(newAffiliateViewModel);
                    return Json("success");
                }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

So rewrite JS code and Action method like I said. In ajax request u MUST name data parameters SAME like in controller action

```
data: { newAffiliateJSON: b}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. After adding the code I am getting:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 

What might be the problem?

Comment: @TomSawyer Where you get this error? Can you attach some picture?